# How to allow only properties that are keys in another property in the same object

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript interface representing a JSON object that has a specific format required by the API I am calling (which is also in my hands to a certain extent) that can be simplified as follows:

```js
interface myCustomJson {
    id: string;
    properties: { [key: string]: 'one' | 'many' };
};
```

I want the `properties` object to describe what other properties exist on the object, where each of these properties is either an instance of `myCustomJson` itself or an array thereof (depending on the value in `properties`). I tried the following:

```js
interface myCustomJson {
    id: string;
    properties: { [key: string]: 'one' | 'many' };
    [key: keyof myCustomJson['properties']]: myCustomJson | myCustomJson[];
};
```

but Typescript gave me the error "`An index signature parameter type cannot be a union type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.`" so I applied the suggested fix, obtaining:

```js
type myCustomJsonPart = {
    id: string;
    properties: { [key: string]: 'one' | 'many'; };
}
type myCustomJson = myCustomJsonPart & {
    [key in keyof myCustomJsonPart['properties']]: myCustomJson | myCustomJson[];
};
```

but then I get errors like "`Property 'id' is incompatible with index signature`", and changing the `&` into `|` just doesn't give the required type.

A typical use for this interface is an object like this:

```js
const x: myCustomJson = {
    id: '1',
    properties: {
        header: 'one',
        children: 'many',
    },
    header: {
        id: '2',
        properties: {},
    },
    children: [],
};
```

How can I tell it that any additional properties must be keys in the `properties` object? Is it even possible in Typescript?
If it is possible, the next step would be to allow the additional properties to be an array only if the corresponding value in `properties` is `'many'`, and similarly for `'one'`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this to work, you have to explicitely define your schema one way or another (so typescript known whats it's dealing with).

I fiddled around and came up with this:

```
/**
 * Can filter some keys from an object, based on their type.
 */
type FilteredKeys<T, U> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? P : never;
}[keyof T];

/**
 * Common Json "node" type.
 */
type JsonNode<Prop> = Prop & {
  id: string;
  properties: {
    [key in FilteredKeys<
      Prop,
      JsonNode<unknown> | JsonNode<unknown>[]
    >]: Prop[key] extends Array<JsonNode<unknown>>
      ? "many"
      : Prop[key] extends JsonNode<unknown>
      ? "one"
      : never;
  };
};

/** interfaces used to describe the structure */
interface Root {
  header: JsonNode<Header>;
  children: JsonNode<{}>[];
}

interface Header {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  buttons: JsonNode<Button>[];
}

interface Button {
  text: string;
}

/**
 * instantiation
 * try changing "one" to "many" & vice-versa
 * try changing types inside object themselves
 */
const x: JsonNode<Root> = {
  id: "1",
  properties: {
    header: "one",
    children: "many",
  },
  header: {
    id: "2",
    properties: {
      buttons: "many",
    },
    description: "",
    title: "",
    buttons: [
      {
        id: "10",
        properties: {},
        text: "Home",
      },
    ],
  },
  children: [],
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! And I don't mind creating interfaces for each instance; they are limited and might prove useful later on. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's actually possible to achieve what you're seeking.
If I understand correctly you're trying to abstractly type, what is to the Typescript Compiler (TSC), unknown key names based on the keys existing in the `properties` property in the parent json.
TSC doesn't provide runtime type checking, only compile time, and so at the point of compilation it's impossible to confirm whether those keys exist in an object that your api hasn't served yet.

FWIW a better way to describe key value pairs in your interfaces would be something more along the lines of:

```
type keyValue = 'one' | 'many';
interface myCustomJson {
  id: string;
  properties: Record<string, keyValue>;
}
```

Comment: I don't need the checks in the runtime, but as in the example above, it will almost always be used with object literals, so I just wanted the type hints there.

Comment: Does using a `Record` have any benefits over the index signature here?

Comment: Ah I see, sorry I misunderstood - I notice you said it has a specific format. I'll try to have a think over more options to see if theres any way. Regarding your second comment, in terms of differences between the types there is no difference. It's a utility type that really just helps write more consistently and its the more common pattern I see so at least to me and others it helps convey more readable type information to humans. Thats was why I tried to word it as a "better way to describe" rather than your choice being incorrect.